# Allow questions to be easily transfered between Stack Overflow and Super User

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, migration

Who thinks it would be useful to be able to switch a question over from Stack Overflow to Super User with an easy click or two?

That way, if you ask a question in the wrong forum, you just send it over to the other without all the extra typing.

Is there something similar already?

Comment: Why not between any two stack-exchange sites.. that would be awesome

Comment: Welcome to Meta, Jamison!  As the answerers have already said, this feature more or less already exists.  I just want to add that you shouldn't do the extra typing yourself.  If your question deserves to be moved, it will be done for you, and extra typing on your part is just creating a duplicate (which would then need to be merged, which is even _more_ work).

Comment: additionally if you need a question migrated (and can't vote to close), flag it for moderator attention.

Comment: I think Jamison wants to do this for his own questions though, not other's. Having to vote for your own stuff to be moved can be frustrating.

Answer (score 4):

Once you get enough reputation and can vote to close, you can vote to move it to a different Stack Exchange. I believe moving is only supported between Stack Overflow, Super User, and Server Fault, but I also think I read somewhere that eventually, related Stack Exchanges will be "linked" so that questions can be moved between them.

Answer (score 3):

This is already possible!

One of the close options is: Belongs on Super User (and vice versa).

If you don't have the rep to vote to close, you can always flag it for moderator attention, to have it migrated

Answer (score 2):

The others are right, but as a visual aid, here's a screenshot of the close dialog. There's a completely non-freehand red rectangle around the migration options:

[image: Screenshot of the close dialog on SO]